React component receiving undefined props
I have a simple React app(created with vite), where i am passing a list of objects to a component Carts, Carts component simply parses the list and returns JSX.
But there is a error pointing that the passed list to the Carts component is not reaching, it is reaching as undefined, also i noticed that Carts is getting called multiple time, (i am in strict mode, but i believe even in strict mode it is called only 2 times.) and in those extra calls it is not getting props properly.
Error Msg:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Carts (Carts.jsx:13:16)
    at renderWithHooks (chunk-M324AGAM.js?v=aec0e7ae:11546:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (chunk-M324AGAM.js?v=aec0e7ae:14924:21)
    at beginWork (chunk-M324AGAM.js?v=aec0e7ae:15912:22)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (chunk-M324AGAM.js?v=aec0e7ae:3672:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (chunk-M324AGAM.js?v=aec0e7ae:3697:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (chunk-M324AGAM.js?v=aec0e7ae:3731:39)
    at beginWork$1 (chunk-M324AGAM.js?v=aec0e7ae:19763:15)
    at performUnitOfWork (chunk-M324AGAM.js?v=aec0e7ae:19196:20)
    at workLoopSync (chunk-M324AGAM.js?v=aec0e7ae:19135:13)

Carts.jsx Code
const Carts = ({ listCart }) => {
  //below console log is getting printed 4 times
  console.log("inside listCart");
  let topMessage;
  //here the listCart is reaching empty
  if (listCart.length === 0) {
    topMessage = `No Products in Cart`;
  } else {
    topMessage = `Cart Elements`;
  }
  return (
    <Carts>
      <h1>{topMessage}</h1>
      {listCart.map(({ name, description, price, _id }) => (
        <Cart name={name} description={description} price={price} key={_id} />
      ))}
    </Carts>
  );
};
export default Carts;

App.jsx
function App() {
  const list = [
    {
      name: "Digital Camera",
      description:
        "A digital camera with a 24MP sensor and 4K video recording capabilities.",
      _id: 9,
      price: 600,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div className="carts">
      <Carts listCart={list} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

My Observation:
If i print something inside Carts component, its getting printed 4 times, once is okay , second one is called by react to check for purity,that is also fine, but then again it gets called two times and receives listCart as undefined.

The code looks fine. I feel there is a problem with how you are fetching cartItem and storing it in const list. If you are making and api call and fetching the cartItem then use a state like const [list, setList] = useState([]) and set the list in a useEffect like useEffect(() => { setList(cartItem) }, [cartItem])

try to console listCarts in Carts component and check the type of it.
also make sure cartItem is imported correctly and have an array in it.

@JayendraAwasthi no, cartItem is not coming from an API, it is just a constant array stored in another js file, it was a long list that's why I just stored it in another file.thanks for responding.

@nazirhussain, that is the problem Carts component is getting called multiple times and in last call it is receiving listCart as undefined, and breaking the react frontend with a error stated above.it is receiving listCart as array in initial calls.

try to wrap Carts component in React memo or find out the reason why it  rendering multiple times

In the returned JSX template of your Carts component, you make a recursive call to itself, with no props:
const Carts = ({ listCart }) => {
  // etc.
  return (
    <Carts> {/* Recursive call without props */}
      <h1>{topMessage}</h1>
      {/* etc. */}
    </Carts>
  );
};

This is very likely the reason for your extra 2 calls.
You probably want to use a React Fragment instead, e.g. using the diamond notation:
const Carts = ({ listCart }) => {
  // etc.
  return (
    <> {/* Or <React.Fragment> */}
      <h1>{topMessage}</h1>
      {/* etc. */}
    </>
  );
};

